# Undefined reference errors in gcc when compiling on another machine

Tags: c, gcc

I wrote a program (myreader.c) to manipulate a RFID reader.

I compile by type "make" in the root of the package, makefile is shown below

```
  # CC and CFLAGS are varilables 
  CC=gcc
  CFLAGS = -c
  # -c option ask g++ to compile the source files, but do not link.
  # -g option is for debugging version
  # -O2 option is for optimized version
  OPTFLAGS = -O2 -g

  myreader    : src/myreader.c
          $(CC) $(OPTFLAGS) src/myreader.c src/crypto1.c src/nfc-utils.c -lnfc -o ./bin/myreader 

  # clean all the .o and executable files
  clean:
          rm -rf bin/myreader
```

and it works well on my original machine(64 bits, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS), and the only problem is, when I type make, the warning info would come up.

```
  src/myreader.c:519:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘printResult’ [enabled by default]
  src/myreader.c:211:3: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘printResult’ was here
```

But /bin/myreader works well.

---

However, when I move the package to another machine(64 bits, Ubuntu 11.10), and type make in the same way as in the original machine.

Error messages in the below appears:

```
  berln@ubuntu:~/桌面/useful code$ make
  gcc -O2 -g src/myreader.c src/crypto1.c src/nfc-utils.c -lnfc -o ./bin/myreader
  src/myreader.c:519:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘printResult’ [enabled by default]
  src/myreader.c:211:3: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘printResult’ was here
  /tmp/ccrKvhjm.o: In function `mf_enhanced_auth':/home/berln/桌面/useful code/src/myreader.c:373: undefined reference to `nfc_configure'
  /home/berln/桌面/useful code/src/myreader.c:380: undefined reference to `nfc_configure'
  /home/berln/桌面/useful code/src/myreader.c:390: undefined reference to `nfc_configure'
  /home/berln/桌面/useful code/src/myreader.c:434: undefined reference to `nfc_configure'
  /tmp/ccrKvhjm.o: In function `mf_configure':
  /home/berln/桌面/useful code/src/myreader.c:484: undefined reference to `nfc_configure'
  /tmp/ccrKvhjm.o:/home/berln/桌面/useful code/src/myreader.c:489: more undefined references to `nfc_configure' follow
  /tmp/ccrKvhjm.o: In function `main':
  /home/berln/桌面/useful code/src/myreader.c:155: undefined reference to `nfc_connect'
  /home/berln/桌面/useful code/src/myreader.c:213: undefined reference to `nfc_disconnect'
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make: *** [myreader] Error 1
```

I have no ideas why this error happened on only one machine instead of both.

**If you need more information, you can download the package [here](http://homepage.ntu.edu.tw/~b98901160/myreader.tgz).**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is nfc_configure declared? we need to see code

Comment: The first error (conficting types for 'printResult') is because you need to declare the `printResult` function before it is used. The simplest is to move it to before you use it the first time.

Comment: To Mark:nfc_configure is declared in line 183 of src/nfc.c in the package.

Comment: To @JoachimPileborg: Thanks, the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your `nfc` library is missing or not installed properly on your other computer.

One of the options you pass to the linker is `-lnfc`, which tells it to link to the `nfc` library. Your errors are coming from the linker, which cannot find the `nfc_configure` and other `nfc_` symbols. This means that the linker cannot find these symbols. Check the `nfc` library installation.

Comment: But I include all the needed files in the package,and compile works on my original machine.

Comment: It seems to be the source of the problem!Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is in the `nfc` library, but the linker doesn't complain that it's missing, so something wrong with it. Try to recompile it. If it's a package check that it's the same version as on the other server.